# post_save cause IntegrityError while having onetoone relation in User and Profile model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i am extending django User model by onetoone relation wit Profile model.and i want to create a profile of a user when User instance is created so i use post_save signal.when i create a user(using register view) a profile is also created with blank and null values which is what i want . but when i try to login with that user IntegrityError appears.

views.py

```
def register(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = CreatUserForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():
        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
        new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
        new_user.save()

        return render(request,'accounts/registration_done.html',{'new_user':new_user})
    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/registration.html', {'user_form':user_form})
else:
    user_form = CreatUserForm()
    return render(request,'accounts/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form})

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    user_edit_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,data=request.POST)
    profile_edit_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile,data=request.POST)

    if user_edit_form.is_valid() and profile_edit_form.is_valid():
        user_edit_form.save()
        profile_edit_form.save()
        messages.add_message(request,messages.SUCCESS,'profile updated')
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',{'user_edit_form':user_edit_form,
                                                            'profile_edit_form':profile_edit_form})
else:
    user_edit_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
    profile_edit_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',{'user_edit_form':user_edit_form,
                                                        'profile_edit_form':profile_edit_form})
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 primary_key=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
   DOB = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
   mobile_no = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
   address = models.TextField(max_length=250,blank=True)
```

signals.py

```
from accounts.models import Profile

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

apps.py

```
 from django.apps import AppConfig


 class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'

    def ready(self):
        from django.db.models.signals import post_save
        from accounts.signals import create_user_profile
        from django.contrib.auth.models import User
        post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, 
                             dispatch_uid='create_user_profile')
```

Error:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://example:8000/accounts/login/

Django Version: 2.1.1
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',
'social_django']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in 
_execute
85.return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
"accounts_profile_user_id_49a85d32_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(5) already exists.
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" 
in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in 
_get_response
126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in 
_get_response
124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in 
view
68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in 
_wrapper
45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in 
sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in 
_wrapper
45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in 
_wrapped_view
142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in 
_wrapper
45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in 
_wrapped_view_func
44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in 
dispatch
61.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in 
dispatch
88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in 
post
142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in 
form_valid
90.         auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in 
login
132.     user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, 
user=user)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in 
send
175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in 
<listcomp>
175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in 
update_last_login
20.     user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in 
save
73.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
718.                        force_update=force_update, 
update_fields=update_fields)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in 
save_base
758.                 update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in 
send
175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in 
<listcomp>
175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "F:\schoolp\accounts\signals.py" in create_user_profile
4.     Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in 
manager_method
82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, 
**kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
413.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
718.                        force_update=force_update, 
update_fields=update_fields)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in 
save_base
748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, 
force_update, using, update_fields)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in 
_save_table
831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, 
update_pk, raw)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in 
_do_insert
869.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in 
manager_method
82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, 
**kwargs)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in 
_insert
1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in 
execute_sql
1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in 
execute
100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in 
execute
68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, 
executor=self._execute)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in 
_execute_with_wrappers
77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in 
_execute
85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from 
exc_value

File "F:\schoolp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in 
_execute
85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: duplicate key value violates unique constraint 
"accounts_profile_user_id_49a85d32_pk"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(5) already exists.
```

Comment: what I found is that whenever there is update on the User model at that time also post_save signal execute but i don't want that so the simple solution is using created arguments. I observe this while posting the errors in question. so thanks stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey post save will trigger when ever you will update the particular user instance.

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

or check if instance is new

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: thanks for your precious time . i figured out the solution and i have done it by checking the instance is new.